# Juntar los chunks de una petición HTTP/HTTPS en Nodejs

Tags: nodejs, http, https, requests

Estoy aprendiendo Nodejs y me ha surgido una inquietud ¿Cual es la forma correcta de juntar los "chunk" y transformarlos a texto/json dentro de una petición http/https?

```
var http = require('http')
var http = require('https')
options = {
    port: 443,
    hostname: "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
    method: "GET",
    path: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
}
var request = http.request(options, (response) => {
    var body = []
    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
    })
    response.on('end', (data) => {
        body = body.join("").toString()
        console.log("Headers: ", response.headers)
        console.log("Body: ", body)
    })

    response.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error("Error: ", err.stack);
    })
})
request.end()
```

Para ser más específicos la linea en cuestión es:

```
body = body.join("").toString()
```

¿Es realmente esto correcto?¿Esta forma está sujeta a errores que puedan romper una posible respuesta?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Para tu caso podrías establecer la codificación usando: `req.setEncoding('utf8')`, así te ahorras el `toString()` al final. Eso siempre que estés seguro que el mensaje es de tipo `String` y no datos binarios. Y en cuanto a si es correcto almacenar los datos en un `Array` y luego hacer `join()`, no veo ningún problema. La [documentación](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_stream) lo hace usando el operador `+=` para un tipo `String`. Saludos

Comment: Vengo de muchos lenguajes y frameworks que manejan completamente las `request`, es primera vez que me topo con uno donde debo juntar los "paquetes" para armar el `body` de la petición yo mismo. Me causa curiosidad y dudé si una simple concatenación podría asegurar la integridad de mi `request` en su totalidad.

Comment: Si te preocupa hacerlo por tu cuenta, podrías usar alguna librería que lo hiciera por ti. [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) es muy popular. A la vez, [`ExpressJS`](https://expressjs.com) es un *framework* muy utilizado para trabajar con NodeJS, básicamente por el manejo de funciones middleware y su potente enrutador. Trabajar directamente con el cliente `http` de NodeJS es una aventura, y puede llegar a ser bastante engorroso para aplicaciones muy grandes. Saludos